# Connecting Viewmodels in areas

Tags: c#, javascript, mvvm, coffeescript

I am working on MVC Areas where I am bundling all coffeescripts as different viewmodels and rendering them in my layout page and specific pages that require corresponding coffee scripts. There are two errors which I couldn't figure out the solution.

1) {"The controller for path '/bundles/underscore' was not found or does not implement      IController."}
    Underscore is a js file. I have done few things to make it work, like not specifying version of bundletransformer in project file etc. But none of them really worked.

2) Javascript runtime error: XXXXViewModel is undefined. This ViewModel is a coffeescript. 
    I have tried many solutions but nothing worked.

If I move the controller which is specific to area and which corresponds to the above mentioned viewmodel, outside the area to default area, everything works fine. I can see the viewmodel populates on my page. But if I have my controller in area, the view which renders this viewmodel is not being generated on the webpage.
For a note, I have few more coffeescripts as viewmodels and I think, none of them are working if I use areas. I don't know if I am missing a link like configuration settings etc, which connects areas and viewmodels.

I hope someone can help me solving this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I am using Attributing Routing to route prefix every view in a controller inside an area by using [RouteArea("AreaName")]. When I commented it, everything works fine. But, I think it is weird not giving area name as starting of the path. 
I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: The prefix you are provided "AreaName" should be same as object in your model